# Javascript/jQuery .each and syntax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, each

I'm having some trouble writing a function to change a background image on a div on document.ready

I haven't made a jsfiddle as i think the problem is just my poor (but improving) jQuery skills. Please let me know if you think one is needed.

Background Info ->
I have a collection of div's with a class of portlet-visible or portlet-hidden, each of these div's will have another class of red-arrow (or a different color, but once i have one color it should be easy to extrapolate). When the page loads i would like a function that can find all divs with a class of portlet-hidden or portlet-visible and see if those have a class of red-arrow. If they do then change the background image src to a different value.

Im really struggling to work this one out, and any help is much appreciated.

My HTML

```
<div class="portlet-visible red-arrow"></div>
```

My CSS

```
div.portlet-visible
  {
    position:absolute;
    top:12px;
    right:10px;
    background-image:url(../images/red-arrow-up.png);
    width:14px;
    height:14px;    
  }
```

And finally my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".portlet-hidden" && ".portlet-visible").each(function()  {
            if ($("this").hasClass(".red-arrow")) {
                $(this).css(background-image, url('"url(../images/blue-arrow-up.png)"')
            };
        });

    });
```

Comment: Please let me know if i can give any more information. Thanks

Comment: Why is this line of code a string: `if ('$("this").hasClass(".red-arrow")') {`.  It should be this: `if ($("this").hasClass(".red-arrow")) {`.

Comment: I've changed that in the javascript

Comment: What do you think `".portlet-hidden" && ".portlet-visible"` is doing? Do you have a `url` function defined? It seems more like you want `.css('background-image', "url(../images/blue-arrow-up.png)")`, `background-image` is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple selectors should be separated by a comma(`,`) and also `css` method takes a string or a map. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".portlet-hidden, .portlet-visible").each(function()  {
            if ($(this).hasClass("red-arrow")) {
                $(this).css('background-image', "url('../images/blue-arrow-up.png')")
            };
        });

    });
```

Comment: this code still has errors in it. see my answer... also comma separated classes represent an *OR* condition, not an *AND* condition.

Comment: @j-man86 - OP needs OR condition only read the question once again don't go by OP's code it has lot of mess.

Comment: $(this).hasClass(".red-arrow") is an error. There shouldn't be a class selector next to 'red-arrow'. hasClass() only accepts a class.

Answer (score 2):

I would have written the selector this way

```
 $(".portlet-hidden, .portlet-visible")
```

Comment: you spotted 1 out of 3 major failures

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a specific reason you want to do this with jQuery you should just use CSS...

```
div.portlet-visible
{
    background-image:url(../images/red-arrow-up.png);
    width:14px;
    height:14px;    
}
div.portlet-visible.red-arrow
{
    background-image:url(../images/blue-arrow-up.png);
}
```

Any div with the class "portlet-visible" is defined in the first block, and any div with the classes "portlet-visible" *and* "red-arrow" will use the same css, but also apply the new background image.

http://jsfiddle.net/johncmolyneux/gcm5b/

Answer (score 1):

First... Archer's answer is spot on-- what you're trying to do with jQuery can be done with CSS alone.

But if for some reason you do need jQuery, a few things are wrong here.

First, as justtkt said in his answer, your selector is wrong. There is no need (and is syntactically *wrong*) to use conditional operators like && or || in a jQuery selector. This is simply because there is *already* conditional syntax *built in* to CSS, upon which jQuery selectors are directly based.

```
.this-class.that-class
```

Selects all elements with **both** `.this-class`, and `.that-class`.

```
#this-id.that-class
```

Is a very (possibly overly) specific declaration that select an element (there should only be one ID per page) with **both** #this-id and .that-class

For more on selectors, please read this very thorough, complete, and educational link http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

**Additionally and importantly**

This line:

```
$("this").hasClass(".red-arrow")
```

Is wrong! hasClass does not require a selector (the ".") because it only takes *a class*. It should be

```
  $("this").hasClass("red-arrow")
```

**Also!!**

```
 $(this).css(background-image, url('"url(../images/blue-arrow-up.png)"')
```

This line has some errors... should be:

```
 $(this).css("background-image", "url(../images/blue-arrow-up.png)")
```

although I think the following syntax is easier:

```
css({'background-image' : 'url(../images/blue-arrow-up.png)'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is just incorrect.  If you want to match things with both classes, it'd be:

```
$('.portlet-hidden.portlet-visible').each( ...
```

If you want to match *either* of the classes:

```
$('.portlet-hidden, .portlet-visible').each( ...
```

The expression `".portlet-hidden" && ".portlet-visible"` will always evaluate to just `".portlet-visible"`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `&&` two selectors together, use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) like `$(".portlet-hidden, .portlet-visible")` or the [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to build up your jQuery.

Your current line is actually anding the two strings together, which I believe will return boolean true in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`if ('$("this").hasClass(".red-arrow")') {` <--- this condition is a string here

Should be:

```
if ($(this).hasClass(".red-arrow")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change in selector `".portlet-hidden,.portlet-visible"`
2. change if condition to `boolean` from string
3. change in `css`.

   ```
   $(".portlet-hidden,.portlet-visible").each(function(){
      if ($("this").hasClass("red-arrow")){
        $(this).css("background-image", "url('../images/blue-arrow-up.png')");
     }
   });
   ```